# Why is the value of the instance variable set in a Groovy closure not visible outside of it?

Tags: groovy, scope, closures

**Question**

Why does `methodA()` print `set within run` instead of `set within closure`?

**Code example**

```
class GroovyClosureVariableScopingTest extends Script {

    String s

    Object run() {
        s = "set within run"
        println "value of s in run(): $s"

        [1].each {
            s = "set within closure"
            println "value of s in each()-closure: $s"
            methodA()
        }
    }

    void methodA() {
        println "value of s in methodA(): $s"
    }
}
```

**Actual output**

```
value of s in run(): set within run
value of s in each()-closure: set within closure
value of s in methodA(): set within run            // <- Surprised to see the original value
```

**Expected output**

```
value of s in run(): set in run
value of s in each()-closure: set within closure
value of s in methodA(): set within closure        // <- Whould have expected this value
```

**Elaboration**

I haven't quite understood how variable scoping works in the above example. I would have expected `s` to be a property (a public instance variable) of the class and I thought that I was assigning it a value from within the `each`-closure which would be retained. But that does not seem to be the case.

Why does `s` not keep the value which it was assigned from within the closure?

**Solution / workaround**

Passing `s` as argument to `methodA()` works. See lines commented with `// Change`.

```
class GroovyClosureVariableScopingTest extends Script {

    String s

    Object run() {
        s = "set within run"
        println "value of s in run(): $s"

        [1].each {
            s = "set within closure"
            println "value of s in each()-closure: $s"
            methodA(s)              // Change
        }
    }

    void methodA(s) {               // Change
        println "value of s in methodA(): $s"
    }
}
```

**Reference**

[Closures - Formal Definition](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures+-+Formal+Definition)

> At the same time, the variables are still available normally to the
>   enclosing scope, so the closure may read/change any such values, and
>   code from the outer scope may read/change the same variables.

**Versions**

- Groovy 1.8.6
- Groovy-Eclipse plugin 2.8.0
- Eclipse Platform 3.8.1

Comment: what groovy version is this and how do you run this class's code?  with `2.3.6` and a slightly simpler version I get the expected result.  With your code (without extending `Script`) it also works as expected)

Comment: @cfrick I've added the information to the question above.

Comment: might as well be the older verison or a bug there.  have you tried with `setS(...)`?

Comment: Can you try Groovy 1.8.9?

Comment: @cfrick It indeed works with `setS("set within closure")`. Strange. :-/ Thank you!

Comment: @AaronDigulla Unfortunately not because we get the system prepackaged. But the next release is supposed to contain a Groovy 2.x version.

Comment: Extremely odd. I suspect a bug somewhere. Can you run the code in a debugger? Then you could see the object "id" and see if you have different strings.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you don't have a `def s` inside of the closure?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I'm sure that there is no `def s` inside of the closure because the code example above shows all the code there is. However, good call with the debugger: the `s` in the closure has a different id than the `s` outside of the closure when I use `s =`. But interestingly enough, it's the same id when I use `setS(...)` as suggested by @cfrick.

Comment: Try "show definition" in your debugger; also try different names for `s` to make sure you're not accidentally hit an inner field of the closure or a binding of the script.

Comment: @cfrick I tested it with a clean new installation of Eclipse 4.3 and Groovy 2.3.4. Same behaviour.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I renamed `s `to `myString`, but same behaviour. "Open declaration" goes to the same variable. The debugger shows `error during the evaluation` when stopping right after the assignment within the closure and inspecting the expression.

Comment: @Lernkurve `groovy.lang.Script` right?  then there is something off, with the way you run it.  Using your code above on command line executes correctly (i used 2.3.6 and 2.2.2).

Comment: @cfrick Thank you very much for the testing and confirmation! I summarised it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25867377/33311). PS: Yes, `groovy.lang.Script`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After user cfrick confirmed that it works on his machine, I ran it from the console and it indeed works.

**From console**

```
C:\temp>java -jar C:\...\lib\groovy-all-1.8.6.jar C:\temp\GroovyClosureVariableScopingTest.groovy
value of s in run(): set within run
value of s in each()-closure: set within closure
value of s in methodA(): set within closure // <- Here
```

**With clean Eclipse installation**

But I still don't get the original script to run with a clean installation of

- Eclipse 4.3 Kepler
- Groovy Eclipse Plugin http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.3/
- Groovy Compiler 1.8.x and also 2.3.4

**Summary**

I still don't know why it doesn't work -- even with a clean installation of Eclipse.
However, it works from the console, it works on cfrick's machine and there is a workaround.

Comment: After running the process in Eclipse, go to the debug perspective and open the context menu for the terminated process. One of the two nodes should have an entry "Properties". If you select that, then you can see the classpath which Eclipse uses. 1. Look for anything odd in the classpath. 2. Try the same classpath from the console.